# Changing original layout path in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

i'm trying to change orginal path for layouts in my ZF application.

```
$viewsPath = '../application/_layouts';
$options = array('layoutPath' => $viewsPath, 'layout' => 'layout');
Zend_Layout::startMvc();

//Initializing Zend_View
$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
$view->setBasePath($viewsPath);
```

ZF trying to find layout in /application/_layouts/scripts

`addBasePath()` in Zend_View_Abstract makes `$this->addScriptPath($path . 'scripts');`

I need to use /application/_layouts/layout.phtml instead of /application/_layouts/**scripts**/layout.phtml

How to make ZF ignore 'scripts' folder without reloading `Zend_View_Abstract::addBasePath()`?

Comment: Oh! i'm sorry. i've spent 2 hours on it :(
but problem was in Zend_Layout::startMvc(**$options**);

Comment: Alternative - in case of you using zend_application - u can use the ini-directive: `resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"` and change the path to your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the standard `Zend_Application_Bootstrap`, you can set these variables in your application.ini and the framework will do the rest:

```
resources.view.helperPath                     = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
resources.layout.layoutPath                   = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/layouts"
```